# Find a transition matrix from S to B.

Tags: linear-algebra, transition-matrix

I was asked this for the previous question:
Find the coordinates of $ [u]_s = ( 1,2,3) $ relative to the basis $ B = {(0,2,1), (-2,1,0),(1,1,1)}  $. Next I need to find a transition matrix I have set this up as [B|S]. In the text it says to turn this into the form $ [I_3|p^{-1}] $ by gauss jordan elimination. So then should I use row reduction on B and should S be written as $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: You don’t need a transition matrix for a single vector. You can just solve a system of linear equations as in [mvw’s answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1997419/265466), below, by performing Gauss-Jordan on $[B\mid u]$. This is equivalent to finding the product $B^{-1}u$—and $B^{-1}$ is your “transition matrix.” You can, of course, compute this matrix by row-reducing $[I_3\mid B]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve
$$
u = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}           
= u_1 b_1 + u_2 b_2 + u_3 b_3
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3
\end{pmatrix}           
$$
The bit about the transition matrix I do not get.

Doing Gauss-Jordan and ending up with $[I\mid p^{-1}]$ is what you can do if you want to invert a matrix $p$.